# C# Selenium how to get all links to list and click random

Tags: c#, selenium

I would like to get links to my list which I already seeing it on my page.

But there is one circumstance, it will be only matched keywords with links should be in list. Like if its `abc.com`, it should be get only `abc.com links`. So that means there is `no external link`.

After that, should be **click to links randomly** which i get from list.

Basically; click random link on page.

- Select all internet links on page
- Click random one
- Repeat it

Comment: just use findElements, and xpath of "//a[contains(@href, "abc.com")]... then pick a random element to click if size > 0.   If the page is using javascript to populate the DOM remember to use a webdriver wait and possibly check for stale element exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is correct you want a method wherein you can pass a specific link as parameter, if there is no link that is passed you are to click a random link from the list.

Please see sample implementation below.

```
   //Click one link randomly
    private void ClickRandomLink(string linkText = null)
    {
       //get all links
        var links = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText))
        {
            var link = links.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttribute("href").Equals(linkText)) ??
                       throw new Exception($"Link with name: {linkText} not found");
            link.Click();
        }
        else
        {
            //click random element in list
            links.ElementAt(new Random().Next(0, links.Count - 1)).Click();
        }
     }
```

Click all available links randomly

```
    private void ClickRandomLinks(string linkText = null)
    {
        //get all links
        var links = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).ToList();

        //click all links matching predicate
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText))
        {
            var linkElements = links.Where(x => x.GetAttribute("href").Contains(linkText)).ToList();
            if(!linkElements.Any()) throw new Exception($"Links with name: {linkText} not found");

            //Generate random order
            var randomElements = Enumerable.Range(0, linkElements.Count-1).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
            randomElements.ForEach(x => linkElements.ElementAt(x).Click());
        }
        else
        {
            //click all links randomnly
            var randomElements = Enumerable.Range(0, links.Count-1).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
            randomElements.ForEach(x => links.ElementAt(x).Click());                
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added a new method to click all links randomnly and to click links matching your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Create a web element list with the elements you found on the page with the links. Then create another list with valid abc.com list and fill it with the correct links. Assert the lenght of the both lists are equals. Then create a random number, pick the index of web element list(`LinkElements`) then click that element.

```
List<WebElement> LinkElements = driver.FindElements(By.Id(“element id”));

List<string> ValidLinks = new List<string>();  

foreach(WebElement LinkElement in LinkElements){
  string LinkString = LinkElement.GetAttribute("href");
  if(Equals("abc.com", LinkString.SubString(0, 7))){
    ValidLinks.Add(LinkString);
    }
}

CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(Links.Count, ValidLink.Count);

Random r = new Random();
LinksElements[r.Next(0,LinksElements.Count)].Click();
```

Comment: gives too many errors. and I didn't understand what to write on the second line.

Comment: on the second line you should change the element selector. 
Basically, you should collect all the elements in to an array with FindElements method. then into the foreach you should check the elements href attribute values are abc.com, if it is add them into another list and compare them.Now i am gonna update the answer.